# Why does my jQuery snippet using for each class not support setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following bit of code isn't working for some reason, it doesn't like the setTimeout part, instead the only working version I can do is without the delay...

```
jQuery(".divhere").hide();
if(jQuery('.divhere').length >= 1){
    jQuery(".divhere").each(function() {
        setTimeout(function(el) {
            jQuery(this).slideDown("slow");
            jQuery(this).show();
        }, 1000);
    }); 
}
```

Only working one is:

```
jQuery(".divhere").hide();
if(jQuery('.divhere').length >= 1){
    jQuery(".divhere").each(function() {
        jQuery(this).slideDown("slow");
        jQuery(this).show();
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Inside the setTimeout handler `this` refers to the window object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` context is being missed in `setTimeout` scenario. If you try to `console.log(this)` inside `setTimeout`, you will find `window` object.

> Use [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind): JavaScript’s Bind Allows Us to Set the this Value on Methods

Try this:

```
jQuery(".divhere").hide();
if(jQuery('.divhere').length >= 1){
    jQuery(".divhere").each(function() {
        setTimeout(function(el) {
            jQuery(this).slideDown("slow");
            jQuery(this).show();
        }.bind(this), 1000);
    }); 
}
```